# Bad word filter also deletes embeds

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i have a problem with this code, it doesnt like embeds. It will automaticly delete any embeds from other bots. Is there anyway to stop this from happening.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
   if msg.author == client.user:
       return
   with open('BadWords.txt', 'r') as f:
       BadWords = f.readlines()
       for line in BadWords:
           if msg.content in line:
               await msg.delete()
       await client.process_commands(msg)
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Add the content of the file BadWords.txt to the question. Looks like there's a word in the file that is matching the embed code.

Comment: Well there is currently just the f word in there so idk why it’s doing that

Comment: I dont know if is the case, but if the `msg.content` is blank and the file has a blank line then the message will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

This most likely happens because you have an empty line in your .txt file, which means that Python matches the empty string with the empty content. You have a few options... *for clarity I include the surrounding code*

You can check if the specific line is empty

```py
for line in BadWords:
    if line == '':
        continue
    if msg.content in line:
```

Or you can remove it before you start looping

```py
BadWords = f.readlines()
try:
    BadWords.remove('')
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Lastly it's also possible you ignore the message if it has no content, as this can also happen if someone sends a file or attachment.

```py
if msg.author == client.user:
    return
if msg == '':
    return
```